# How to check Rails app's thread safety for Puma

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, heroku, puma

I wish to deploy my Rails app to Heroku using Puma webserver. However, I am not really sure whether all Gems are thread safe. Reading all Gems' source code is not feasible option for us.

Is there a way to automatically check all Gems for thread safety? Or does Puma complain/display specific error log if thread unsafe code were executed/detected?

Comment: FWIW Thread safety in ruby is iffy at best. This is one of the reason's Jose created Elixir. I wouldn't count on thread safety in any ruby code.  Your best bet is use rubinius or jruby

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Thread safety can not be detected in general. If there was some way to detect it automatically, probably your compiler/interpreter would warn you about it.
[Race conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#Computing) can not be detected by automatic systems, they can be even hard to reproduce.

Depending on your interpreter:

- `CRuby` has [GIL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Interpreter_Lock), so using `Puma` with it is pointless.
- If you are using `JRuby` or `Rubinius` than you can probably benefit from `Puma` and most probably the gems you use have documented their methods/classes thread-safety. In this case all you need is to check your code.

Comment: "An interpreter which uses GIL will always allow exactly one thread to execute at a time, even if run on a multi-core processor"=> as long as the memory is shared, isn't it still possible for deadlock, race conditions, liveness issue to occur?

Comment: OK, you are right about that. The GIL simplifies most of the possible threading problems that may occur. You are right, the main point is that you can not test code for thread safety in some automated manner and using `Puma` for a Ruby implementation with GIL have no benefits over using `Unicorn` for example.

Comment: Great article: https://bearmetal.eu/theden/how-do-i-know-whether-my-rails-app-is-thread-safe-or-not/

Comment: Even with the GIL, using multi-threading has its advantages. Sure, you won't be able to run your program with more than 1 CPU at the same time, but all the time spent waiting after the network or IO in general can be used to execute something else in the same process. Plus you'll end up using way less RAM. See Sidekiq for example.

Comment: I am still searching for up to date benchmarks for `MRI Ruby` runing `Puma` and `MRI Ruby` runing `Unicorn`. If you can show something I would agree but until then I think this is just a speculation. Sure, all the things you say are true in theory but in practice, especially when talking about parallel execution, things became very different.

Comment: There was and probably still persists an issue with Unicorn being susceptible to slow clients attack as a form of trivial DoS. This was the reason why Heroku now recommends use Puma instead of Unicorn as the Ruby web server.

Comment: @DavidUnric Isn't it why they usually recommend running Unicorn behind a reverse proxy, like Nginx?

Comment: @art-solopov It can partially help in subset of situations but dedicated attack can simply bypass nginx's buffer size and hang the Unicorn anyway. I've read the technical background but can't find the link now.

Comment: this article is also interesting https://tomkadwill.com/benefits-of-switching-from-unicorn-to-puma